# How to add a sticky footer on top of an absolute positioned image

Tags: html, css, css-position, footer, sticky-footer

How would I go about adding a sticky footer to the bottom of my page that isn't fixed. I made the mistake of adding the footer to my website last. The footer would be on top of an absolute positioned image. I tried using the absolute position, min-height solution but it didn't work. The footer isn't at the bottom of the total page (it will be at the bottom of the page of the initial starting position). Here is the HTML code and CSS code. I'm not sure where the issue/conflict and I have tried scanning and looking in the code but can't see it. HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title> Home </title>       
        <meta name="description" content="A music review website">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body class="homepage">
        <header>
            <a href="index.php"> 
                <img class="banner" 
                src="Pictures/second_banner_image_blue.jpg">
            </a>
        </header> 
        <nav> 
            <a class="homelink" id="activehome" href="index.php">Home</a>
            <a class="reviewasonglink" href="Review_a_song.php">Review a 
            song</a>
            <a class="reviewslink" href="Sort_by_rating.php">Reviews</a>
            <a class="faqlink" href="faq.php">FAQ</a>
            <a class="contactlink" href="contactpage.php">Contact us</a>
            <form method="get" action="search.php">
                <input type="text" name="q" class="searchbox"  
                placeholder="Search for a song, album or artist here...">
                <input type="image" name="Search" 
                src="Pictures/magnifyingglass.png" class="searchbutton">
            </form>
        </nav>
        <a href="Review_a_song.php"><img class="homepic1" 
        src="Pictures/concert_edit.jpg"></a>
        <a href="Review_a_song.php"><p class="hometitle1">Review your 
        favourite music</p></a>
        <a href="sort_by_rating.php"><img class="homepic2" 
        src="Pictures/songreviews_edit.jpg"></a>
        <a href="sort_by_rating.php"><p class="hometitle2">Read 
        comprehensive reviews</p></a>
        <a href="faq.php"><img class="homepic3" 
        src="Pictures/questions_edit.jpg"></a>
        <a href="faq.php"><p class="hometitle3">Questions?</p></a>
        <footer>
            <p>Copyright</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: opensans; src: url('fonts/OpenSans.tff');
    font-family: roboto; src: url('fonts/Roboto.tff');
    font-family: robotobold; src: url('fonts/RobotoBold.tff');
    font-family: headings; src: url('fonts/adamcg.otf');
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.homepage {
    background-attachment: scroll;
}

.homepic1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.homepic2 {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateY(500px);
}

.homepic3 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateY(972px);
}

header {
    height: 86px;
}

a {
    text-decoration-line: none;
}

.background {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

a:visited {
    color: currentColor;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 53px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    color: white;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    margin-left: 46px;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(428px);
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.review_content{
    margin-left: 53px;
    transform: translateY(50px);
    color: white;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:white;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
}

nav a{
    width:11.4%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: black;
}

.homelink {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.hometitle1 {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 90px;
    font-size: 65px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: headings, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 200px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #565656;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hometitle2 {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 65px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: headings, sans-serif;
    color: #16308d;
    margin-left: 190px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #0f2163;
    transform: translateY(600px);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hometitle3 {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 65px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: headings, sans-serif;
    color: #510000;
    margin-left: 440px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #450000;
    transform: translateY(1070px);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.reviewasonglink, .reviewslink, .contactlink, .faqlink, .homelink {
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.reviewasonglink:hover, .reviewslink:hover, .contactlink:hover, 
.faqlink:hover, .homelink:hover {
    background-color: #404040;
    color:#e6e6e6;
}

#activesortbyrating, #activereviewasong, #activecontact, #activefaq, 
#activehome {
    background-color: #5e5e5e;
    color:#e6e6e6;
}

#activesortbyrating:hover, #activereviewasong:hover, #activecontact:hover, 
#activefaq:hover, #activehome:hover {
    background-color: #404040;
    color:#e6e6e6;
}

.banner {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
}

.searchbox {
    float: right;
    width: 230px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 29px;
}

input::placeholder {
    color: black;
    font-size: 12.8px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

input[name="q"] {
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0.8px solid black;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}

.formentries {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 53px;
    color: white;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.warning {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.formentry {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.searchbutton {
    float: right;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    transform: translateX(273px);
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

textarea {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

select {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.formbox {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.contactform {
    padding-left: 53px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.contactinfo {
    padding-left: 53px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    color: white;
    font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
}

.contactentry {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.contactmessage {
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.searchtitle, .searchartist, .searchalbum {
    color: white;
    transform: translateX(53px);
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.searchtitle {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.FAQ {
    margin-left: 53px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.genreoptions {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    border-spacing: 1;
}

.ratingoptions {
    max-width: 960px;
    transform: translateX(45px);
    margin-top: 277px;
    position: absolute;
    border-spacing: 1;
}

.reviews th {
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #024457;
    color:white;
}

.reviews {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: 44px;
    margin-top: 520px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.genreoptions thead th {
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #8a97a0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.ratingoptions thead th {
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #8a97a0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.ratingoptions tr {
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.genreoptions tr {
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.reviews tr {
  background:white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.ratingoptions tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #e8eeef;
}

.genreoptions tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #e8eeef;
}

.reviews tr:nth-child(even) {
    background:#e0ebfc;
}

th, td, tr {
    padding: 8px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.circle {
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

input[type=radio]{
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

label > input + img{ 
  cursor:pointer;
  filter: brightness(0%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

label > input:checked + img {
    filter: brightness(100%);
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.genreoptions, .ratingoptions td {
    width: 33%;
}

.reviews tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color:#d4d5d6;
}

.genreoptions tbody td:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.ratingoptions tbody td:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.reviews th, td {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
}

.sortinfo {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(45px, 468px);
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.filterbutton {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(45px, 405px);
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color:white;
    border: 0.5px solid midnightblue;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.body {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.noreviewsinfo {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(45px, 420px);
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.submitbutton {
    height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color:steelblue;
    color: black;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #27496d;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.submitbutton:hover {
    filter: brightness(70%);
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

.nosearchresults {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 53px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
}

footer {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: why you choose ``absolute`` property  for all elements, you can use  ``position: fixed`` property to the ``nav`` and ``footer`` only

Comment: Could you add screenshots of what happen when you add a fixed position footer?